# Fixed footer hides the text above

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm building a webpage and I need the footer at the end of the page to be Fixed in the page. i.e. when I'm scrolling to remain on bottom on the page.

CSS:

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

But the result in the browser is wrong. Footer hides me the text above.

http://i.imgur.com/2lXt0Bi.png

How can I display it like this? :

http://i.imgur.com/yY5RfE4.png

Comment: post your HTML, CSS and any associated JS in a fiddle..

Comment: maybe add some margin/padding-bottom: height-of-you-footer.px to the body, or content, or some tags you used over there; @ArinCool makes a good point

Comment: Set to your footer `position: absolute`.

Comment: I used margin-bottom and now it looks fine.
Thank you guys!

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

Change z-index of your footer. Element with greater z-index is always in front of an element with a lower index value.

```
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:120px;
    z-index:10;
}
```

[This](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) and [this](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/) have nice illustrations on z-index and stack-ordering.
Also, add some padding to the content to make it look good.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `margin-botom` to your main content (where the text appearing) would solve this issue. The `value` of `margin-bottom` will be equal as your **footer**'s `height`.

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fx5c1fq0/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a sticky footer, you need to give your footer specific height and then use this height as padding-bottom for your body.

For example:

```
body { padding-bottom: 120px; }

footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:120px;
}
```

Comment: I use an image (tile) for the background footer.
How can I adjust the height?

Comment: You mean that you use a repeating background image? May I see your css?

Comment: That's correct. It look fine with margin-bottom. 
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Why does it have to be `padding` and not `margin`?